# Rank math Category Title

Tags: wordpress

I want to set the category title but I couldn’t do it.

My site has 1 main category and 2 subcategories. There are thousands of categories like this.

Main Category: Iphone
-Sub Category: 13 Pro Max
–Subcategory of Subcategory: 2022

The title I want to create:
2022 Iphone 13 Pro Max

Sorting
Name of the subcategory of the Subcategory – Name of the Main Category – Name of a subcategory

How can I make this structure for all categories? It is impossible to do it manually because it is an archive site and there are thousands of categories like this. Please tell me this is possible with rank math.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break it down:

first you want to get the Parent Category of the given post or you can define it manually.

Within the loop

```
$parent = get_the_category();
```

Then we'll get the first category

```
$parent = get_category($parent[0]->category_parent);
```

then from there get the child

```
$child = get_categories( array( 
   'parent' => $parent->term_id 
) );
$child = get_category($child[0]->term_id);
```

and the grandchild

```
$grandchild = get_categories( array( 
    'parent' => $child->term_id 
) );
$grandchild = get_category($grandchild[0]->term_id);
```

then echo it out

```
echo get_cat_name($grandchild->term_id) . ' ' . get_cat_name($parent->term_id). ' ' . get_cat_name($child->term_id);
```

Combined

```
$parent = get_the_category(); 
$parent = get_category($parent[0]->category_parent);
        
$child = get_categories( array( 
   'parent' => $parent->term_id 
) );
$child = get_category($child[0]->term_id);
        
$grandchild = get_categories( array( 
    'parent' => $child->term_id 
) );
$grandchild = get_category($grandchild[0]->term_id);

echo get_cat_name($grandchild->term_id) . ' ' . get_cat_name($parent->term_id). ' ' . get_cat_name($child->term_id);
```

This should output

```
2022 iPhone 13 Pro Max
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your response. I tried the code but it does not say that it does not take the category that is grandchild. There is no problem with categories with parent and child. As it is, the output is "13 Pro Max Iphone".

Comment: check that the post has the grandchild category selected

Comment: I checked, but my request has nothing to do with the post. I should be able to show them without a post. I found a code like this.
get_category_parents( $cat, true, ' &raquo; ' );
Thanks to this code, it also shows other categories connected to the category like breadcumbs. but can I break it down and sort it as I want?